# Database query / Custom Class to JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, converters

I have a jquery event calender in my application which must be feed by JSON input.
At the moment the imput looks like this:

```
[   
{ "date": "1352636408000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Poker Freak", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" },    
{ "date": "1351775676000", "type": "demo", "title": "Poker Freak", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cveniris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url": "http://www.event2.com/" },   
{ "date": "1351764876000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Poker Freak", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "http://www.event3.com/" } ]
```

Its saved in a JSON file which is a demo-file from the event calender.

On the other hand I have a MSSQL Table which conterns the data in the Event-Table (Date as DateTime, Type as string and so on).

I get the data with this command:

```
        public static List<Event> GetAllEvents()
    {
        using (CyberDBDataContext db = new CyberDBDataContext())
        {
            return (from a in db.Events select a).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now - how to convert the MSSQL Return query (a List of Events) into JSON?

Comment: Consider using Json.Net. It is a powerful component which can serialize objects to JSON strings.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) Library for that. This would be the easiest way (and in my opinion it is one of the best libraries out there for JSON).

Use the <strike>second</strike> fourth formatting from these examples

```
  string defaultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"\/Date(1234656000000)\/"}

  string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":new Date(1234656000000)}

  string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"}

  string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new TicksDateTimeConverter());
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"1234656000000"}
```

Following your snippet with the custom DateFormatter:

```
public static string GetAllEvents()
{
    using (CyberDBDataContext db = new CyberDBDataContext())
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((from a in db.Events select a).ToList(), new TicksDateTimeConverter());
    }
}
```

**Edit:** *in case you are using ASP.net MVC*

Dunno if it also applies to any version before ASP.net MVC4 but since version 4 JSON.net is the default JSON serializer. So You wan't need to implement it any longer.

**Custom Converter**

I recommend you to implement a custom converter like below. Basically it is the same as the JavaScript Converter but it should only return Ticks.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities;

namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Converters
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Converts a <see cref="DateTime"/> to and from a JavaScript date constructor (e.g. new Date(52231943)).
  /// </summary>
  public class TicksDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      long ticks;

      if (value is DateTime)
      {
        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime utcDateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        ticks = JsonConvert.ConvertDateTimeToJavaScriptTicks(utcDateTime);
      }
#if !PocketPC && !NET20
      else if (value is DateTimeOffset)
      {
        DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)value;
        DateTimeOffset utcDateTimeOffset = dateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime();
        ticks = JsonConvert.ConvertDateTimeToJavaScriptTicks(utcDateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime);
      }
#endif
      else
      {
        throw new Exception("Expected date object value.");
      }

      writer.WriteValue(ticks);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="JsonReader"/> to read from.</param>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <param name="existingValue">The existing property value of the JSON that is being converted.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    /// <returns>The object value.</returns>
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      Type t = (ReflectionUtils.IsNullableType(objectType))
        ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType)
        : objectType;

      if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
      {
        if (!ReflectionUtils.IsNullableType(objectType))
          throw new Exception("Cannot convert null value to {0}.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, objectType));

        return null;
      }

      if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartConstructor || !string.Equals(reader.Value.ToString(), "Date", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        throw new Exception("Unexpected token or value when parsing date. Token: {0}, Value: {1}".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, reader.TokenType, reader.Value));

      reader.Read();

      if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Integer)
        throw new Exception("Unexpected token parsing date. Expected Integer, got {0}.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, reader.TokenType));

      long ticks = (long)reader.Value;

      DateTime d = JsonConvert.ConvertJavaScriptTicksToDateTime(ticks);

      reader.Read();

      if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndConstructor)
        throw new Exception("Unexpected token parsing date. Expected EndConstructor, got {0}.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, reader.TokenType));

#if !PocketPC && !NET20
      if (t == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
        return new DateTimeOffset(d);
#endif

      return d;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kovu I fixed the return value. I guess you can also spare the `ToList()`

Comment: Nice, thank you. Nearly everything works but the DateTime. I get "new Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" instead of whished "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: @Kovu I added a custom converter which should be able to do this.

Comment: @Kovu Did you managed to get it working? I didn't get any feedback from you for the last edit.